# How to find out my laptop secondary memory's interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ssd, pop-os

I own this old laptop that is starting to feel way too slow, it uses a HDD as secondary/nonvolatile memory, and I'd like to buy a SSD to replace it, is there a way to find out the memory interface through Pop OS(Debian/Ubuntu based)?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the HDD interface is SATA; however, if the laptop is *very* old, it might be PATA.

It might be easiest to find out the HDD model, and then you can google for its interface and other relevant specifications, like size (thickness) and power consumption.

Helpful commands:

```
sudo cat /sys/block/sda/device/model
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Replacing a 2.5" SATA HDD with a SATA SSD should be easy.

If it's a PATA (=IDE) HDD, you might try your luck with cheap M.2 SATA to IDE converter cards from Aliexpress and the like; such a converter card equipped with a M.2 SATA module should fit within the space of a 2.5" HDD, although in the worst case you might have to 3d print or otherwise build an attachment frame for it, depending on how the existing HDD fits inside the laptop. I've successfully revived one retro-laptop using this method.